# How to Query Database Name in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How do I query the database name in Oracle SQL Developer? I have tried the following and they all fail:

`SELECT DB_NAME();`

`SELECT DATABASE();`

Why do these basic MySQL queries fail in SQL Developer? Even this one fails too:

`show tables;`

**EDIT:** I can connect to the database and run queries such as:

`select * from table_name_here;`

**EDIT 2:** The database type is `Oracle`, this is why `MySQL` queries are failing. I thought it was related to the database client not the database itself. I was wrong. I'll leave the question as is for other as lost as I was.

Comment: Everyone has their own extensions to basic SQL, and mysql's no exception.

Comment: I'm realizing this more and more! This is using an Oracle database. I'm not sure if there's another name for that.

Comment: Figured it out once I recognized I'm running an Oracle database, not a MySQL one: `select * from v$database;` and `select ora_database_name from dual;`

Comment: If you're going to minus the question, please indicate why. Perfectly legitimate question seeing I didn't know the answer when I asked it, and the discussion within here lead me to the answer.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette: not even knowing what RDBMS you were connected to probably made people waste their time trying to figure out your problem. I can understand why people would see this negatively. And as you said, once you realize you're talking to an Oracle server, finding the answer to your question is a trivial search.

Comment: @Mat, thanks. I got those down votes after I edited the question with such info. so I guess they were too quick to jump and I wasn't sure how to (or if I should) restructure the question. But thanks for explaining. I do understand their point of view.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Once I realized I was running an Oracle database, not MySQL, I found the answer

`select * from v$database;`

or

`select ora_database_name from dual;`

Try both. Credit and source goes to: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=520376.

Comment: Note: apparently the security rights to these are not the same. In my case select ora_database_name from dual works, the other gets an invalid table error.

Comment: the result from these two sql is different....which is correct?

Answer (score 20):

try this:

```
select * from global_name;
```

Comment: this allows to query even through a dblink: 
`select global_name from global_name@dblink_identifier`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following command to know just the name of the database without the extra columns shown.

```
select name  from v$database;
```

If you need any other information about the db then first know which are the columns names available using

```
describe v$database;
```

and select the columns that you want to see;

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but you can also get some useful info from the `V$INSTANCE` view as well. the `V$DATABASE` displays info from the control file, the `V$INSTANCE` view displays state of the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Whoops, didn't check your question tags before answering.

Check that you can actually connect to DB (have the driver placed? tested the conn when creating it?).

If so, try runnung those queries with F5

Comment: I can connect to it and run queries and have been for months. Just added that in the question.

Comment: The answer, once I realized I was running an Oracle database: 'select * from v$database;' and/or 'select ora_database_name from dual;'

Answer (score 0):

To see database name,
startup;

then type
show parameter db_name;

Answer (score 0):

DESCRIBE DATABASE NAME; you need to specify the name of the database and the results will include the data type of each attribute.