# How to get all database names in oracle using c#?

Tags: c#, oracle9i

I like to know any way to get all the database names in oracle using c#. I think we are not able to get all database names using query. I like to get all database names in oracle 9i server in C# code. Is their any way for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "database"?  If you are using it in the Oracle sense, there is only one database per connection, the database you are connected to.  But maybe you mean it in the way that many other relational database products (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) do where a SQL Server "database" is roughly analogous to an Oracle "schema".

Comment: Not actually. I meant in connection string we will give database name. Their may contain more than one database . I like to get these names in c#.

Comment: If you really mean "database" in the Oracle sense, you probably can't do this in general.  It's possible to have multiple databases on a server though it's very common to have just one database per server.  Theoretically, you could get a list of servers where databases are installed, connect to each one, and try to determine what services are running (this will depend on what operating system the servers are running) but that is a rats nest of special cases.  If your organization does something like publishing connection information for all databases to an LDAP server, you could use that.

Comment: OOps.. Actually my requirement is to get all the database names in oracle 9i using c# code. So their is no way to get these by using c#? I can see the database names in one folder.

Comment: OK, now I'm really confused.  What do you mean when you say that you can "see the database names in one folder"?  Do you maybe mean to ask how to parse the client's tnsnames.ora in order to get all the TNS aliases that are defined?

Comment: I have created 2 database similar to like this http://docs.oracle.com/html/A95906_01/ch1.htm .. I can see these database names in path like c/oracle/...

Comment: Is the question, then, how to determine what databases are running on your local system when you assume that all Oracle Homes relate to a running database and that you know the root path of all Oracle Homes?  That should be possible (though of limited utility in general).  9i has been deprecated so long that I don't recall the default directory structure any longer, you'd probably want to tell us exactly what you see and exactly what you want to extract.

Comment: I can see database names as folders in c/oracle/oradata path.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to query databse server according to oracle specification :

[How to Query Database Name in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978047/how-to-query-database-name-in-oracle-sql-developer)

```
select * from v$database;
```

and execute this command in relative .NET adapter.

See  a code example here: [Oracle database connection data access from C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43bb4bc5-7cc5-4d2d-a668-364a2a96eb6e/oracle-database-connection-data-access-from-c)