# How do I prompt input for database on command line?

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, command-line, sqlplus

I need to prompt ENTER DATABASE NAME.

But It doesn't and it still connects. What database does it connects to? It says "CONNECTED TO "

[image]

Here's the batch code.

```
@echo off

sqlplus &username/&password@&db

ECHO About to exit.

timeout t/ 30

:pause
```

Comment: try `select * from v$database;` to show database name. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978047/how-to-query-database-name-in-oracle-sql-developer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ampersand (`&`) is used for SQL*Plus substitution variables. You are supplying it on the Windows command line, where it means something else; when you exit from the client you'll see something like:

```
'username' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'password@' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'dbname' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The batch file will treat it as a command separator, so it passes nothing to SQL*Plus, and only looks at what's after it once that program has completed.

The username/password prompts are completely indpendent of your command line values. It will be connecting locally to whatever your ORACLE_SID environment variable is set to, or if your TWO_TASK environment variable is set then it will be using that as a TNS connection.

You can prompt for the three pieces of information in a SQL script as you attempted in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28183129/266304), or prompt for them from the batch file and pass them on the command line, in a loop if you want to handle mistakes as Mofi showed; but as I mentioned in a comment on that answer, putting the credentials on the command line isn't very secure. You could use a 'heredoc' to use the batch variables directly in a code snippet, rather than using a SQL script.

For example, just to mimic what you were doing before, you could replace Mofi's `sqlplus.exe` line with:

```
@(
echo whenever sqlerror exit failure
echo connect %SqlUserName%/%SqlPassword%@%SqlDatabase%
echo select * from dual;
echo exit 
) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog
```

Or to run commands from a script file:

```
@(
echo whenever sqlerror exit failure
echo connect %SqlUserName%/%SqlPassword%@%SqlDatabase%
echo @myscript.sql
echo exit 
) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog
```

Note that since you are doing the `connect` with your supplied credentials before calling the script, the script itself should not have a `connect` statement, and it won't be be able to see you Windows % variables. (It's possible to make them visible but I don't think you need to). Also note that the `whenever` statement means it won't attempt to execute the script if the connect fails.

You can run as many scripts as you want with more `echo` statements, and/or other statements not in scripts. But if any script includes an `exit`, or causes an error that exits, that will terminate the whole session and not just that script.

---

As any error in your SQL will cause an exit, not just a credential problem, you'll loop around when you don't want to, as you noted in a comment. You have a couple of options:

- You could add `whenever sqlerror continue` after the `connect` statement; but then if you hit an error it will continue and try to run subsequent commands anyway, and depending on what you're doing that might end up with strange results. But if you're creating objects then you might have protective drops that you don't mind throwing errors you want to ignore.
- You could use `whenever sqlerror exit 2` before the connect and `whenever sqlerror exit 1` after it. Then your batch script can decide whether to loop to prompt again based on the return value, 1 or 2. (I'm not really familiar with Windows exit codes so other values might be more appropriate to avoid confusion).

Or you could mix both to have the failure of specific commands handled differently, so you ignore an error on a `drop` say, but anything else exits the script. Depends what you're doing and what your detailed requirements.

[Read more about the `whenever` behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10825/pc_09err.htm#i12340).

Comment: I edited your /nolog line to this: `) | sqlplus.exe -s /nolog  @C:\Users\njediaz\Desktop\conn.sql` .. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok I added this line, `if errorlevel 0 sqlplus /nolog  @C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\conn.sql`  , and it's now working. Thanks

Comment: is this possible? `if errorlevel 0 sqlplus /nolog @C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\conn.sql` .. will it run the conn.sql to the database credentials I entered?

Comment: @ladiesman1792 - if you have a script you want to run, put that instead of the select from dual in the example; in that same `@(...)` block, do `echo @myscript.sql` before the `exit`. Don't start a new SQL*Plus session, it won't have the credentials from the first one; and don't have a `connect` in your script.

Comment: Ok, I tried and it's now working. Thanks. But when the .SQL file encounters an error, the credentials will prompt again, how can I prevent that from happening? I still want it to continue even the .SQL file have an error. Image for reference - > http://i.imgur.com/70FKfoS.jpg

Comment: can I add another sql file in this line? `echo @myscript.sql` like, `echo @myscript2.sql` then another line, `echo @myscript3.sql`

Comment: @ladiesman1792 - updated with some options for error handling. Which now I've changed it, maybe should have been a separate question... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Try undefining the variables before running the script:

```
undefine username;
undefine password;
undefine db;
```

and make sure you add the undefines in the script - probably best done at the very end.