# Oracle11g error: table or view does not exist when using INSERT INTO

Tags: database, oracle11g, sql-insert

After creating a table I would like to insert data but I've encountered an error.

Creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Buildings"(
  "idBuilding" Integer NOT NULL,
  "buildingName" Varchar2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  "city" Varchar2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  "street" Varchar2(30 ) NOT NULL,
)
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO Buildings VALUES(1, 'Empire State', 'New York', 'West');
```

and the error is

```
SQL Error: 00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
```

I know that there are a lot of similar questions here but I couldn't find any solution. I've tried using GRANT and it didn't help. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: You're creating a table named "Building", but inserting into a table named "Banki"?

Comment: @Waterstraal that was a mistake. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you created the table with quotes and some lowercase letter, you have to use quotes in your insert statement as well. `"Buildings"` instead of `Buildungs`.

Identifiers are case sensitive in Oracle, but identifiers without quotes are automatically turned to uppercase. Therefore, `"ABC"`=`ABC`=`Abc`=`abc`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Oracle that adding values' of names with " symbol at the start and at the end of an object's name doesn't show its' symbol in database but it's still somehow saved in database.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO "Buildings" VALUES(1, 'Empire State', 'New York', 'West');
```

Comment: Not a bug.without quotes, names are turned to uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Well per your latest edit, check and make sure that you have selected the correct database under which you have created the table named `Buildings`.

See this post [How to Query Database Name in Oracle SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978047/how-to-query-database-name-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Comment: My bad, I've pasted the wrong command and made a typo. Table name is "Buildings" and I'm trying to insert into Buildings. I've edited my post.

Comment: how to do it? I'm quite new when it comes to DB. I'm inside my .sql file and when I click on the left on Tables I can see all of my created tables.

Comment: @codddeer123, see edit again and search in SO or Google